# How can I make a multipage image from an image list

Tags: c#, bitmapimage

I have one multipage image `abc.tiff`, I have to do some drawing on each page and save that as one multipage image into some `D:\xyz` location.

I am using below code for that:

```
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"abc.tiff");
    int count = bitmap.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < count ; idx++)
    {

        bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, idx);
        // save each frame to a bytestream
        MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream();
        // below 3 lines for drawing something on image...
        Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(bitmap, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tmp);
        g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, x, y, width, height);

        tmp.Save(byteStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
        tmp.Dispose();
        // and finally adding each frame into image list    
        images.Add(Image.FromStream(byteStream));
    }
```

After that I want to save my modified multipage image on `D:\xyz` location.

Could you please suggest me how can I obtain one multipage image from `List<Image>` images?

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is taken pretty much directly from [Bob Powell](https://web.archive.org/web/20141223070416/http://bobpowell.net/generating_multipage_tiffs.aspx):

Assuming

```
string saveName =  "c:\\myMultiPage.tiff"    // your target path
List<Image> imgList = new List<Image>();     // your list of images
```

When the list is filled you can do this:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
// ..

System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder enc = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag;

// create one master bitmap from the first image
Bitmap master = new Bitmap(imgList[0]);
ImageCodecInfo info = null;

// lets hope we find a tiff encoder!
foreach (ImageCodecInfo ice in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
    if (ice.MimeType == "image/tiff")  info = ice;

// we'll always need only one parameter
EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

// save the master with our parameter, announcing it will be 'MultiFrame'
master.Save(saveName, info, ep);

// now change the parameter to 'FramePage'..
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);

// ..and add-save the other images into the master file
for (int i = 1; i < imgList.Count; i++)
    master.SaveAdd(imgList[i], ep);

// finally set the parameter to 'Flush' and do it..
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
master.SaveAdd(ep);
```

All praise to Bob Powell!!